# In Vega-Lite, 'config.legend.columns' doesn't appear to work when using 'resolve'. Is there another way of specifying the number of entries per line?

Tags: vega-lite

Here is an [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUADJQBWENgDsQAGhCY6guGhAqQAdxoATetqiLMSGgrgAnXWYUAzGmTSgoDCJjYIAYmxtkTAAVAE8cOAg0TBsGOFUkAA8aKNRQQSQmOEF-BUxtACU2JjZvXQysnPMAZRoALy1UAEYAJlUK7NzMAHU4Fyw0ABZJSXbM7IBhNkEA7UlEsUcANgBmJYAOEABfdvI4BUM3EAhQhBLBAHkcJCg6ULQm1QCaffz0EuwfXUMaGzgodSKbQwZ51cxIQT2aYMBAKVIrVQnM7TWoNIYjLY7ECGJAWCBwTCpUA4vEEgD6RjJTTQAG1QMQIXEHm1sbjGiAWpIWi1+JImvwmpJgk1BqgRmLpCNJAAtbbKemMxrc1Qk9mc7m8nmC4Wi8UjKQjWU7BWCJmoJZLFVs7TqnmSFYCoUiiUSg0yuUms0rBGszBqrl2waOnUu-VSo0AXStpMwFMMZJatM9SpZqptAd5-O1zr1ksNHpADNNjVa0f9Gq5wZzkld4YLRbNAE5Lb7y3aHdndTWw-njYXFWhvWX0xWg53Q3n3VsI1iMqFbEnfSg0iAFEgEOySUh8bHKdSsTEkHDHAEEIuoBCPBk-doAOQACWmoQABPej4YyH814ZIrfdNvTG2KMQGQGwAGsjkwcJ2WEaxdC8Gw2DA9k-kOREYiQuBuiMExUBaLF9jMH4FFcFd7hXZxskOdAGy0VQoIibQAEcGCPdQLHUUh-2SIk1A0dkAEkFFuH88iiTFVESSCaA3ABVBQ6G0eckECcwYDTVRKMEajW10djNG0biUiODoclNCAYGiWJ4j4qAwKmBg8jQMQJJAMwZjsFdoAhRpQBsI8yEaGkQFQkBgMMHxLCUVBgsfQQXzfA5P32JAfyiGdNJebTAPo-jDMxPstyONcN20LcdzjBM5TUfzj1Pc9LwYa92VvAA1AJrkEZ8CkyJg6AgP8ElSNygNUUCIJXBiYKsOjjgw5DtCYYt4PmrCcMsvCCOEthiNI0ByNALSdNovToOY1i8joXEaC4hIeOkzADPQISRNecSsSkyaZLgeTFPQZTVLydTrUyqiypBvjHvZIzeNM3xzI2mI4lyuyHKc1AXKxdzZgorKdKgPS8vQeCLye4lIqsWkQHamxOu63r+rC1RasCqmlqZGcCvlJcjlo1I6RApIHhGMbKbw0YQE-NgGBwbRvFl6csXGyCzvQP4AShDztAAYiaOB1jgFZZrYa5bigtBJXWLaiKsPaQAOkAkDIZKKBvdBkCk0HsvdoWsVCRMVydl3rXdymvZ0hBKax6YccOvHtClmXCahwzEVJ3zsQp6LgvlpmQoCoKQF1-XDa0DKQE0QKDiOJFzjCRj0AgFiVNm2vpiuG47gtqQra54lcWXZN+dAD20E5UXoolxPZfeUpvDPRWxpUibQCm7R1fyVRsc8ovDEbFYuTEXQTc782xR762dtto4HaDv5XfZUfw+0Ue-YD0A774N2QLDkAjpfqOW8Y6eTjmDdA09k5PR0GnHyRwIrIDFsFD48884s0LtrPeB8WhH3LpXfY1FQBt0EPXdkTdWJ-Hgqcc4HczbkUtgVaczNIjTC4l5dONdVraCsD+CIBxXiaxxiAbhcBeGiXyAVIAA).

As you can see I have set 'config.legend.columns' to be 3.  So I am expecting the legend in the rendered graph to only have 3 entries per row.

Before I was using 'resolve', setting 'config.legend.columns' was working for me.  IOW the legend would line break when it displayed the specified number of columns.

After I started using 'resolve', which actually addressed a litany of issues we were fighting, setting the top-level 'config.legend.columns' appears to have no effect whatsoever.

I changed the toplevel 'columns' to different values, no change.

I tried adding a 'columns' entry to each of the layers 'encoding.color.legend' objects, also no apparent change.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? It isn't clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry for not being totally clear.  I updated my question to reflect this.

Basically I set 'config.legend.columns' to be 3, so I am expecting 3 entries (at max) per row in the legend.

The example show is just a quick representation.  We have some charts with many  (>8) legend entries and they just 'run off the right side of the chart' until they decide to wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the covers, Vega is actually giving you 4 separate legends due to the way you have set this up. You can also see this as you have set the legend title to "" four times.

e.g.

[image]

You need to rethink how you provide your data to Vega either reshaping it and/or using Vega directly to give you the flexibility you require.

The following might help you understand what is happening and might be a solution for you (to specify the full domain and range once per legend type)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.0.json",
  "title": "",
  "width": "container",
  "config": {
    "customFormatTypes": true,
    "axis": {
      "labelFont": "Roboto",
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelFontWeight": 400,
      "labelColor": "0x5f6368"
    },
    "legend": {
      "symbolOpacity": 1,
      "orient": "bottom",
      "direction": "horizontal",
      "columns": 3,
      "symbolSize": 400
    }
  },
  "datasets": {
    "dataset_id_1": [
      {"value": 12, "date": "2022-01-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 22, "date": "2022-02-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 66, "date": "2022-03-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 33, "date": "2022-04-10T14:00:00.000Z"}
    ],
    "dataset_id_2": [
      {"value": 22, "date": "2022-01-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 12, "date": "2022-02-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 96, "date": "2022-03-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 33, "date": "2022-04-10T14:00:00.000Z"}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"name": "dataset_id_1"},
      "transform": [{"calculate": "'Holy Handgrenades'", "as": "c"}],
      "mark": {"type": "line", "stroke": "red", "strokeWidth": 2},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "value",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": "Incidents"}
        },
        "x": {
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "field": "date",
          "title": "",
          "axis": {"labelFlush": true, "tickCount": 5}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"name": "dataset_id_2"},
      "transform": [{"calculate": "'Vorpal Rabbits'", "as": "c"}],
      "mark": {"type": "line", "stroke": "blue", "strokeWidth": 2},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "value",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": "Incidents"}
        },
        "x": {
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "field": "date",
          "title": "",
          "axis": {"labelFlush": true, "tickCount": 5}
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "c",
          "title": "a",
          "scale": {"domain": ["Holy Handgrenades","Vorpal Rabbits"], "range": ["red","blue"]}, "legend":{"columns":1}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"max": 100, "min": 20, "group": "top"}]},
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "color": "#1e8e3e", "opacity": 0.08},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "max"},
        "y2": {"aggregate": "min", "field": "min"},
        "color": {
          "field": "group",
          "title": "b",
          "scale": {"domain": ["top", "bottom"], "range": ["#1e8e3e","#d93025"]},
          "legend": {"symbolType": "square", "symbolOpacity": 0.08, "columns":1}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"max": 20, "min": 0, "group": "bottom"}]},
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "color": "#d93025", "opacity": 0.08},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "max"},
        "y2": {"aggregate": "min", "field": "min"},
        "color": {
          "field": "group",
          "title": "d",
          "scale": {"domain": ["bottom"], "range": ["#d93025"]},
          "legend": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"stroke": "independent", "color": "independent"}}
}
```

Comment: Expanding on Davide's explanation and in line with your question @Greg, the main source of the issue here is your use of "resolve". In the previous version of your code, Vega-Lite was likely using a "shared" color legend which meant that setting the columns would work as the different layers were all accessing the same color scale. With the new version, you are instructing the color scales to be "independent", which means that they are now treated as separate legends as Davide pointed out here.

Comment: Thank you both for your insightful responses.

Since we have appx 50 different instances of using multi-layer vega-lite specs, it would be a Sisyphean task to  attempt to migrate how all of the data is provided.

I have an ok workaround that I will deploy (moving the legend to the right side).  And will take a look at vega afterwards.
-g